# Exim настройка DKIM

Tags: exim

Здравствуйте, настраивал dkim на сервере почты. Пользовался статьями: [Массовая почтовая рассылка через Exim или как не попасть в спам](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114852/) и [Debian exim4 настройка mailer](http://likeunix.ru/debian-exim4-mailer/), однако подписи не появляются в письмах. Подскажите, куда копать?

P.S. Если нужны текущие конфиги, пишите какие, выложу.

Comment: предложу совсем другой вариант. если установка на чистый сервер, то можно использовать панельку vestacp.com. простая, аккуратная. email из коробки проходит PASS для DKIM, SPF, DKMI. остается вручную пара шагов, что бы rDNS и HELO подправить.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.Для диагностики предоставьте, пожалуйста:

1. ls -la файл_с_приватным_ключом;
2. конфиг транспорта, отвечающего за отправку писем на удаленный SMTP сервер *;
3. результат вывода `dig txt селектор._domainkey.вашдомен +short` ** .
4. лог отправки сообщения (доступен, как правило в /var/log/maillog или /var/log/exim/main.log);

---

* - если в конфиге транспорта используются макросы - предоставьте также их;

** - селектор необходимо указывать именно тот, который использовался при генерации ключей.

Comment: Похоже, вы оба не понимаете, что такое "конфиг транспорта". Хотя бы потому, что это, например, TCP. И где там макросы???

Comment: А чтобы не было печали - вот: http://habrahabr.ru/post/141534/ Хабр не читаете? А зря!!!

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_smtp_transport.html . Перед тем, как давать комментарий и ссылки на статьи по Postfix (который не обладает собственной реализацией DKIM), в отличие от Exim. Также без понимания сути предмета катигорически не рекомендую использовать HOWTO.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не увидел сразу Ваш вопрос по макросам. Читайте, пожалуйста, http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_run_time_configuration_file.html#SECTmacrodefs .

Comment: Теперь и я прошу прощения! Просто невнимательно прочитал вопрос - в ночи писал, сильно уже спать хотелось. Поэтому написал "не в кассу". Спасибо jaur за правильную информацию!